# Ajax - multiple calls to slow down my server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server

Let's say i have an ajax function in my js code. I am going to use jQuery.

```
function ajaxcall(a, b) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "example.php",
        data: {
            n: a,
            y: b
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    });
}

var interval=setInterval(ajaxcall("Dany", 20), 60000);
```

I'll call this function once per minute and basicly when i change interval time to 500 it will do 120times/minute, thats 120 users.

```
var interval=setInterval(ajaxcall("Dany", 20), 500);
```

The thing is that i know how to prevent multiple calls in my php file, but the problem is that the server must respond every time and that means my server is obligated to work and to process something.

In my php file, i have 6 lines of code which will detect every unneeded call. and 6 lines are almost nothing, but the call exists.

**My question is: How much these types of calls are going to harm my server s performace? Is it something I should worry about?**

sorry for my bad english I hope you understand my question. thanks

Comment: Nothing to worry about. There's always caching.

Comment: Try it out - it might be not practical if you will have really heavy traffic... as well if you get 'slower' then you can always change server to nginx if using apache... as well think about websockets and socketo.me if you're interested in real time communication without making 400 api calls...

Comment: @Andrew i dont understand whats that mean "there's always caching"

Comment: what is your purpose of making too many AJAX calls.

Comment: @AabirHussain if someone change my js script in his browser for example as a said in my post `var interval=setInterval(ajaxcall("Dany", 20), 500);` kind a hack

Comment: I am sorry but i got confuse here **I'll call this function once per minute and basicly when i change interval time to 500 it will do 120times/minute, thats 120 users.**.

Comment: If 120 request coming from 120 users, then its fine but if 120 request made by single user then it may be danger. Are you using CSRF token or some thing similar to prevent hacks

Comment: @AabirHussain yea as i said in my post `The thing is that i know how to prevent multiple calls in my php file`, in 6 lines of code it will detect every other inneeded call and process will die()

Comment: @AabirHussain i'll call this function my site is going to call this function once per minute but what if hacker change this to call 120 times per minute you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answer By Alsciende [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser).

Max Number of default simultaneous persistent connections per server/proxy:

```
Firefox 2:  2
Firefox 3+: 6
Opera 9.26: 4
Opera 12:   6
Safari 3:   4
Safari 5:   6
IE 7:       2
IE 8:       6
IE 10:      8
Chrome:     6
```

So, you don't have any need to worry. But is case you want to avoid multiple calls to that particular function.

You can use session to store user id, time of the call made through ajax. Send user id with every ajax call match user id and check last call time and then make your condition.

*Hope this would help you*

Comment: max connections per second  or?

Comment: these are concurrent connection limit but if it is limited then your call should also be limited. A hacker cannot 100 or 200 call per second.